# Unable to set a condition in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following data set in the test table:

```
create table test
(
columndate date,
columntime datetime
)

insert into test values('2014-01-01','22:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-01-02','06:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-01-03','23:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-01-04','05:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-02-01','10:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-02-01','13:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-02-01','15:00:00')
insert into test values('2014-02-01','05:00:00')      

columndate       columntime
------------------------------------
2014-01-01  1900-01-01 22:00:00.000
2014-01-02  1900-01-01 06:00:00.000
2014-01-03  1900-01-01 23:00:00.000
2014-01-04  1900-01-01 05:00:00.000
2014-02-01  1900-01-01 10:00:00.000
2014-02-01  1900-01-01 13:00:00.000
2014-02-01  1900-01-01 15:00:00.000
2014-02-01  1900-01-01 05:00:00.000
```

Now I want to show only night timing in the result for example:

```
columndate       columntime
-----------------------------------
2014-01-01  1900-01-01 22:00:00.000
2014-01-02  1900-01-01 06:00:00.000
2014-01-03  1900-01-01 23:00:00.000
2014-01-04  1900-01-01 05:00:00.000
2014-02-01  1900-01-01 05:00:00.000
```

For which I am trying the following script:

```
select * from test
where columndate between '2014-01-01' and  '2014-02-01'
  and cast(columntime as time) between '06:00:00' and '23:00:00'
```

Note: I will not get the record of timing `05:00:00`

But when I use the following script:

```
select * from test
where columndate between '2014-01-01' and  '2014-02-01'
  and cast(columntime as time) between '05:00:00' and '23:00:00'
```

Note: I will get expected result but I am getting record of timing `06:00:00`  also which I don't want to show.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't get it... you want only events from 23:00 to 06:00 (ie overnight)?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Yup!

Comment: Howcome is `2014-01-01  1900-01-01 22:00:00.000` in your desired result then when it's not after 23:00? Typo?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Apologize! My typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close: instead of `BETWEEN` you need to use a pair of `>=` and `<=`, because you need times *outside* an interval:

```
select * from test
where columndate between '2014-01-01' and  '2014-02-01'
  and (cast(columntime as time) <= '05:00:00' OR cast(columntime as time) >= '23:00:00')
```

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83795/9)

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your needs??:

```
select * from test
where columndate between '2014-01-01' and  '2014-02-01'
  and cast(columntime as time) between '05:00:00' and '23:00:00' and columntime ! ='06:00:00'
```

Comment: There might be `05:30:00` or `06:30:00` and so on which does not meet my need.